# Dynamically size an array without Redimming it in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently developing a reporting suite that will interface with Microsoft Excel.  The languages that I've used primarily are Java, Perl, and Python.  I would consider myself a novice programmer.  The only reason that I have chosen to use VBA is because it was suggested as the best language to use if programming a Microsoft Office extension.

Those things considered, I absolutely HATE the way that arrays perform in VBA.  Specifically, having to define the size of an array instead of allowing it to grow dynamically.

How do I create dynamic arrays without having to Redim them?  I'm trying to avoid this as it is clearly resource intensive.

The only solution I have found is if you are using a single loop, whereby you can set the number of elements to equal the upper bound of the loop (assuming a count 1 iteration).

What do I do when I'm not using a single loop and this is not an option?

Is Redimming inevitable?

Comment: If you find that you're working with an array which you're constantly re-dimensioning in order to grow it, then you might consider growing it block-wise instead of incrementally. Then just shrink it to the exact size as a final step.

Comment: Of course redimming is inevitable. It just as inevitable as when you're working with arrays in Java or .NET or C# or generally in **any strictly typed language** I know... Everything else is not an array. JS uses a hack, where arrays are actually hashmaps, ruby does a similar trick, python uses `List`s, which explicitly are **not** arrays. If you want to dynamically allocate space for your data, you need a **List** (or a general-type collection). Everything else is just not an array (and bound to be slower)

Answer (score 4):

This is not an "array" but VBA does have a [`Dictionary`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187234) object (this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164502%28v=office.10%29.aspx) is useful too) that might suit your needs.  You need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, but then you can create an untyped keyed dictionary (actually the `Item` property is a `Variant`), which can grow dynamically.  The links have more complete examples, but the usage is basically:

```
Set dict = New Dictionary

'Example for adding item to Dictionary
For i = 1 to 100
    dict.Add Key:=i, Item:=someData
Next

'Example for retrieving item from dictionary by Key
For i = 1 to 100
    Debug.Print dict(i)
Next
```

There is also a `Collection` object as well, which offers similar functionality and similar usage but does not require the added reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, however `Dictionary` provides some more useful methods like `dict.Exists()` to check if a specific key exists.  There are also `.Keys` and `.Items` properties in `Dictionary` that would allow you to extract all of the Items or Keys as a `Variant`-typed array

Even though you explicitly stated that you do not want to redim the array, the only other alternative to adjust the size of an array after creation is to use the `Preserve` modifier on the redim statement.  This will allow some you flexibility in changing the array size after creation.  The reason I said "some flexibility" is you can only change the last dimension of the array.

```
Dim myarray(2, 2)
Redim Preserve myarray(2, 4) 'this works
Redim Preserve myarray(3, 4) 'this is not allowed
```

As you mentioned this is resource intensive as you really are not changing the size of the array, you are actually just creating a new array and copying the contents of the old array into it.

The last option you have is to switch from VBA to .NET.  Assuming you have an appropriate [version of Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office#VSTO_compatibility_and_add-in_functionality) at your disposal, you'll have access to [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) instead of the VBA editor that comes with Office, and then you'll be able to develop CLR-compliant add-ins for Excel and other Office products.  You would then have access to all of the .NET collections.  Again, these aren't "arrays" since .NET arrays have the same limitation (they can't be resized), but you have dynamically sized collections that might suit your needs.

Comment: You're the bearer of bad news here psubsee2003.  Is there no way to define a dynamic array in VBA?

Comment: `Redim Preserve` is the only way to change the size of an array.  This is what `Collection` and `Dictionary` in VBA are for as they are designed to grow as new elements are added.

Comment: @toolshed FWIW you can't magically resize an array in .net or Java either (a numpy array is also fixed-size), and using a `List` instead is just using an abstraction on top of an array; the resizing/copying still happens, only it's done in a way that minimizes it. I fail to see what the OP "HATES" of VBA that isn't also a constraint in other languages. VBA doesn't deserve half the hate it gets.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old question but I would like to add some context to the answers already given.

VBA does not directly provide a type for dynamic arrays and redimming is necessary to change the size. This seems to be inefficient as it potentially entails copying the contents of the array to a new location in memory. However, this is exactly what dynamic arrays do under the hood: they typically double size when they are full and shrink to half the size when they drop below quarter the size. This guarantees an average runtime for adding and removing items of O(1).

So, if you want to use arrays in VBA because of the high speed of index lookups and you also want dynamic size, you can simply emulate this behavior.

Edit:
One small correction. You get O(1) average performance for adding to or removing from the end of the array. Adding at random positions is always O(N) for arrays. (You have to shift everything.) 
If you want to add at random positions, you should better use a linked list, which has bad index lookup performance (enumeration has good performance, however), a skip list, which is more complicated but has good lookup performance sacrificing insert performance, or a hash set, for which key lookups are very fast but which has larger space requirements.